# Is it possible to use a custom resource from some cookbook to create a custom resource in your own cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, dependency-management, chef-custom-resource

I have a cookbook let's say the name of my cookbook is `check` and I am trying to build a custom resource by having the file in the following directory structure : `check/resources/myresource.rb`. In this `myresource.rb` file I need to use a custom resource from another cookbook `line`. How do I use the resource from `line` cookbook in `myresource.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what @Draco already mentioned, the two steps described by him are required steps. In addition to that, the inclusion of the cookbook needs to be done when you call the custom resource in your recipe.

```
# check/resources/myresource.rb

resource_name :myresource
property :cookbook_inclusion, String
property :some_name, String, name_property: true

action :some_action do
  include_recipe new_resource.cookbook_inclusion
  line_resource [...] do
    [...]
  end
end
```

Then while calling it in the recipe you can mention the name of the cookbook that you want to include.

```
# check/recipes/default.rb

myresource 'include' do
  cookbook_inclusion 'line'
end
```

In this way, at convergence, all resources will be available for operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly the same way you would, if you wanted to use it in your recipe.

1. Depend on the cookbook that has another custom resource defined:

```rb
# metadata.rb

depends 'line', '~> X.Y' # add this line, replacing X and Y with line cookbook version
```

2. Use custom resource. You can use it in recipe or in your custom resource, anywhere you can generally use resources. (I used `line_resource` as an example, the real name is different, depending in what file in `line` cookbook it was declared.)

```rb
# check/resources/myresource.rb

action :some_action do
  line_resource [...] do
    [...]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this and it gives me an undefined method error in the *line_resource* line. I used the actual `replace_or_add` resource from line cookbook which is in [link] (https://github.com/sous-chefs/line/blob/master/resources/replace_or_add.rb)

I used `line_replace_or_add [...] do ` and it gave undefined method error. 
Any comments on this, please?

Comment: As you see on line 10 https://github.com/sous-chefs/line/blob/master/resources/replace_or_add.rb#L10 the actual resource name is `replace_or_add`.

Comment: when I use `replace_or_add [..] do` I  still get the undefined method error.